# java.sql.Connection extension for SSH

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh, firewall

I have a MySQL database behind a firewall which can only be accessed via an SSH connection. Does anyone know of an implementation of java.sql.Connection which would allow me to make an SSH connection to this database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use SSH's port forwarding to do this.  While not a pure java.sql.Connection, it will allow you to tunnel the connection through ssh.

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 remote.mysql.host.com
```

This will forward port 3306 on your local machine to port 3306 on remote.mysql.host.com.  This will allow you to connect to port 3306 on your local machine, and it will be tunnelled to remote.mysql.host.com.

If you're looking to do it all in Java, create the ssh connection with [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Comment: How can I establish the connection with MySQL on remote server with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://github.com/newjam/mysql_ssh_tunnel_example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/newjam/test/tunnel/Tunnel.java#L54) using the library [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj).