# how to access a remote database in java which can be accessed only through ssh

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh, mysql-connector

I need to access the remote MYsql database from java which can be accessed only through ssh
SSH tunneling works perfectly fine for my application as most of the linux systems come with built in ssh client.
[java.sql.Connection extension for SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252258/java-sql-connection-extension-for-ssh)

what if i need to access the database from windows system, by using putty or some other ssh client.

can we do ssh tunneling in windows system as if in ubuntu systems.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, see [Using PuTTY under Windows to create an SSH tunnel to your NetManager](http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html). Basically you need to set up a tunnel to the mysql port and then you can use the JDBC as natural without it being aware of the tunneling happening

Comment: this is what i was searching for :)

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of SSH clients for java:

- [Apache MINA SSH](http://mina.apache.org/sshd/)
- [Java Secure Channel (JSCH)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)
- [github.com/shikhar/sshj](http://github.com/shikhar/sshj)
- http://orion-ssh2.sourceforge.net/

Probably you can take a look and see who is going to work for you, but I think jsch could solve your probelm. See examples [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)